# Is it possible to embed Qt Assistant as a widget inside my application?

Tags: qt, touch, embed, qt-assistant

We're running one of our apps on a 8" touch screen and want to add help to it.

Launching Qt Assistant from a menu item works fine for desktop applications, but for touch applications it's far from ideal.

I haven't been able to figure out if it is possible, or permitted to do so?

QAssistant.exe itself seems to come with some license restrictions, but maybe there's another way to do this, like embedding a small web-browser or something.

Have anyone else tackled this, or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out how [QtCreator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator) does this, they have integrated QtHelp which looks exactly like what you're trying to do. The library they use for that is the QtHelp module (I think).

Comment: Thanks. Will look closer. The exact sources are here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master/src/shared/help and they indeed use the QtHelp library (like Yigi said). Actually displaying the help-HTML should be done with QtWebKit or something, I assume?

Comment: I'm accepting this, since looking at the source of some other implementation is the right direction to go. Thanks! (Also, QWebView is used by Qt Assistant, so I was right in that sense..)

Answer (score 4):

You should check the documentation for QHelpEngine and QHelpContentWidget. I think that these classes will meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to actually see how Qt Assistant is implemented, by looking at [the source](https://github.com/qt/qttools/tree/5.11/src/assistant).